# How do I assign value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to type 'AVAudioPlayer?'

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am making a sound effects application, and I am currently trying to get the sounds to play at the push of a button, but I cannot build it out until I can fix the errors. This is an error that I came across, but I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     let noiseMaker = NoiseMaker()
      var player: AVAudioPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

@IBAction func curse(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    noiseMaker.play(sender.tag)
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: getName(tag: sender.tag), withExtension: "wav"){
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer
```

The error it gave me was this:

> Cannot assign value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to type 'AVAudioPlayer?'

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
player.delegate = self
player.prepareToPlay()
player.play()
```